How to integrate this weather API into my jetpack compose app for my first project
I'm trying to make a weather forecast and status finder app by using an API from weatherapi.com . It's my first time integrating an API like that into an android project. i need help. i've included the retrofit libraries into my code and i need a start to finish guide to how i can get the data from the api service using the key and how to have the data display on my screen in a LazyColumn. If some experienced developer could help, I'd be so happy. it'd help me get out of this puddle i'm stuck in
i tried to implement retrofit, but nothing else, please help i'm so confused

To give you a step by step guide for your specific problem is a little difficult as the information provided is not much. But here is  articel that migth be able to help you as it  basically implements exactly your Problem.
https://medium.com/@dheerubhadoria/jetpack-compose-android-app-with-mvvm-architecture-and-retrofit-api-integration-4eb61ca6fbf2
